# Issues in css3 button

Tags: html, css

I'm tring to create a back button based on the  ipad.
I have a button and arrow and can't seem to reduce the height of the arrow to match with the button. If i reduce the height of arrow it doesn't show up properly.

Thanks to sandeep for the arrow style..

Here's my code as to what i hav done so far
http://jsfiddle.net/dVbJr/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily make through this css:-

```
.arrow:after{
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F4F4F4;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    content: "";
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -53px;
    top: -33px;
    width: 45px;
}
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/dVbJr/11/

**UPDATED**

please update your css with this:-

```
    .arrow:after{
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F4F4F4;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    content: "";
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -53px;
    top: -33px;
    width: 45px;
}
```

now its working web-kit browsers...

for more info on pure css based shapes read this article:- http://www.css3shapes.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in an much simpler manner, using just the button. No extra elements.

**EDIT**:
Something like this:

```
.backLstBtn {
    margin: 125px;
    padding: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(#FDFDFD, #F4F4F4);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.backLstBtn:before {
    left: -13px;
    top: 1px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-left: solid 1px #999;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FDFDFD, #F4F4F4);
    content: '';
}
```

You can see it in action here http://dabblet.com/gist/2761845

Comment: but how can i get a curved effect on tip of the button instead of a sharp one ?

Comment: Check it again, I've tweaked it a bit to make it look better where the button meets the :before pseudo-element

Comment: sorry had to accept another one as the answer :) but ur code is awesome

Answer (score 1):

This can be done much simpler. There are some pretty good generators out there: http://cssarrowplease.com/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

reducse image height in photoshop if you want to use big image then use HTMl tag and control height in css...

Comment: He's creating an arrow using CSS. This has nothing to do with images.